# jQuery UI dialog reloads the page when you click on close button. What is wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

In my dialog have two buttons. If I click on the close button the dialog box closes and page reloaded. How to close dialog without page reloading?
My code:

```
add_bankday.dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 400,
            buttons: [{
                id: 'submit',
                text: <?php echo json_encode('Add'); ?>,
                click: function(event){

                    if ($('#password').val() != calendar.resource.password){
                        $('#error').text(<?php echo json_encode('Wrong password'); ?>).css('visibility', 'visible');
                        return;
                    }

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'ajax.php',
                        async: false,
                        data: {
                            op: 'add_bankday',
                            day: $('#new_bank_day').val(),
                            password: $('#ab_password').val()
                        },
                        success: function(res){
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
            {
                id: 'bank_close',
                text: <?php echo json_encode('Close'); ?>,
                click: function(){
                    $('#new_bank_day').val('');
                    $('#add_bankday').dialog('close');
                }
            }]
        });
```

Comment: It seems you have an extra `}`, check your `buttons: [` code.

Comment: I do not have extra }. Checked.

Comment: jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/0pwocy6o/ php code deleted

Comment: try `return false` after `$('#add_bankday').dialog('close');`.

Comment: try return false after $('#add_bankday').dialog('close');

nothing

and return; is not working.

Comment: Well the fiddle clearly doesn't reproduce the problem. Your error is not in the code provided above

Comment: not seen $('ui-button').click(location.reload()), sorry

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea: Since it look like you're using ajax requests make sure you have disabled any normal html form submission controls and use plain html buttons!